# Do I need to dismantle the ballast on a metal halide bulb fixture before replacing with an LED bulb?

Tags: led

Is it necessary to dismantle the ballast on a metal halide fixture before popping in a corncob type LED bulb? Halide is 120w, LED will be @45w.

Comment: LEDs and all consumer goods must survive Power Line transients as defined in the standards.  Not all types of MH ballasts strike the same high voltage and who knows how this affect reliability?

Answer (score 2):

LED light bulbs generally need to be connected to the mains directly, assuming they are designed for 120/240 Volts AC.

LED light bulbs do **not** need a ballast, a ballast is only needed for **gas discharge** lamps like Metal halide and fluorescent lamps. You might even **damage** a LED light by leaving the ballast in place.

So yes, you need to remove it and connect the 120/240 V AC LED bulb directly to the mains.

Comment: Some LED replacements for fluorescents are designed such that the old ballast says in place. Many of them actually will not work if you remove the ballast.

Comment: Read the installation manual carefully. The answer should be there.